# It is possible that Date.now() for file names to create collisions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, multer

I am using Multer middleware in a Node/Express application to serve images to a Vue frontend. I have read that using `Date.now()` will prevent file name collision, but I am designing this with the purpose of adding the functionality to a larger application, so I want to know if it is possible that using `Date.now()`, the app creates duplicated files with the same timestamp. My code is the following:

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, 'public/img'); // Destination folder for uploaded pictures to serve them
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        const ext = file.mimetype.split('/')[1];
        cb(null, `pic-${Date.now()}.${ext}`);
    }
});
```

I am wondering if there is a possibility (and how to achieve it) to get two images with the same name, because the method I am using allows the upload of multiple files at the same time, and I don't know if the Date.now() function can be executed so fast that it generates the same result twice. I left the POST function of my server just to add more context.

```
app.post('/uploadmultiple', upload.array('picture'), (req, res, next) => {
    const imgArray = req.files;
    if (!imgArray) {
        const error = new Error('Please upload a valid image.');
        error.httpStatusCode = 400;
        return next(error);
    }
    res.status(201).json({ files: imgArray });
});
```

If the collision can occur, I don't know what to do because Multer overrides files with the same name, I don't know if there is a way to customize the name of a file if the system finds another with the same name or there is another way to prevent file name collision completely.

Comment: You are right - `Date.now()` has a resolution in milliseconds but it can be executed several times per 1ms. So in order to prevent filename duplication you need to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/tmp

Comment: Or a generator like https://www.npmjs.com/package/flake-idgen

Comment: Thank you very much! the flake-idgen module works perfect for my problem!